# Mysql Extract from Historical Table and Keep Historical Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table machine_info as,

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
|Module |Machine|  VAL  |  FLG  |      Timestamp           |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------------------- +
|  T-01 |  Tron  |   1  |  Y    |   2020-01-01 11:22:33    | 
|  T-01 |  Tron  |   2  |  Y    |   2020-01-01 11:23:33    | 
|  T-01 |  Tron  |   1  |  Y    |   2020-01-01 11:24:33    |
|  T-02 |  Volt  |   4  |  Y    |   2020-01-01 11:25:33    |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
```

I am trying to achieve an outcome where the second a new entry for the table comes (for example, the second last row, **T-01** , **Tron** and **1** appears for the second time at a fresher timestamp value) there is a trigger or something to push only the most latest record to a new table for the repeat entry of Module, Machine and Val but with a newer timestamp.

The new table will be an exact replica of machine_info but holds only one entry for the unique Module, Machine and VAL combination with the latest timestamp. Something like,

```
    +-------+-------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
    |Module |Machine|  VAL  |  FLG  |      Timestamp           |
    +-------+-------+-------+-------+------------------------- +
    |     
    |  T-01 |  Tron  |   2  |  Y    |   2020-01-01 11:23:33    | 
    |  T-01 |  Tron  |   1  |  Y    |   2020-01-01 11:24:33    |
    |  T-02 |  Volt  |   4  |  Y    |   2020-01-01 11:25:33    |
    +-------+-------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
```

If T-01, Tron, 1 appears again in the machine_info table, the replica table should overwrite the existing values of that combination with the newer timestamp value and leave the other rows in the replica as they are. Same applies to all such unique combinations.

In the end there will be one table with all the historical information and another one containing only the most recent records.

What approach should I be taking to achieve this? I am using mysql-5.7.7

Comment: Are both table going to be in the same database or at least in the same connection host & port?

Comment: Yeah, they will be in the same database and same connection host and port.

Comment: So T-01 isn't always 'Tron'?

Comment: It is. But it has a newer timestamp and the other fields next to it can be different. So I want to store the newest row corresponding to the T-01 and Tron into a new table.

Comment: @ChelanYadav . . . Why not just create a view?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a trigger.  Define the destination table, say `machine_info_latest`, to match the original table.  Then add a unique column or constraint on `(Module, Machine, VAL)`.

Then your insert trigger  on `machine_info` can use `insert . . . on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into machine_info_lastest (Module, Machine, VAL, FLG, Timestamp)
    values (new.Module, new.Machine, new.VAL, new.FLG, new.Timestamp)
    on duplicate key update
        FLG = values(FLG),
        Timestamp = values(Timestamp);
```